# I can't override woocommerce.css

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried to override woocommerce.css using child themes, but still nothing.

Folder structures:

> /home/project123/public_html/wp-content/themes/betheme/css/woocommerce.css
>
> /home/project123/public_html/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/css/woocommerce.css

When I've tried to look at the page source the URL points to betheme not to betheme-child. What can I do?

I want to remove this lines, and I don't want to use `!important` because I want to use bootstrap to resolve some responsive problems.

```
.woocommerce .product .product_wrapper .product_image_wrapper .images {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: did you enqueue the css in your functions.php?

Comment: I've tried but still won't works

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra identifier such as the page class or an id

```
`.page-id-16 .woocommerce .product .product_wrapper #sampele-product .product_image_wrapper .images {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}`
```

Comment: But that's a hack.. if I will update the template this will be like at the beginning.

Comment: You should add it to your child theme. It won't be overridden  by any updates then.

Comment: Got a link to look at?